# How to read /proc/pid/status in Android?

Tags: android

I want to read the status file of all processes in an Android system. I check the permission of `/proc/pid/status` files, it is `-r-r-r-`, seems like it could be read from every user, and I have turn `seAndroid` off.

In shell, it works fine, but when I read the file in an application (.apk), it always return "no such file". I think maybe it is the permission issue, but I don't know why, what blocks an application from reading this file.